# What is difference between Bootstrapper.bindDOMParsed( function ) and Bootstrapper.bindDOMLoaded( function )?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

What is difference between Bootstrapper.bindDOMParsed( function ) and Bootstrapper.bindDOMLoaded( function ) ?

Answer (score 3):

With the Ensighten Bootstrapper, bindDOMParsed basically represents the timing for the bottom of the page's  tag existing - bindDOMLoaded is the timing for after all of the elements on the page have downloaded (the page is completely done).